# How to define a language for an independent set problem of a graph?

Tags: formal-languages, graphs

Let a graph $G=(V,E)$ have an independent set $I\subseteq V$ with $\{u,v\}\notin E$ for all $u,v \in I$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ where $|I|=k$.

How can I define the language $L_{P_{Independent Set}}$ to this decision problem?

I know that $I$ could be written as $I = \{u,v\} \in V | \{(u,v)\}\notin E \}$ but don't really understand how to describe the language.

Comment: Let the size of independent set i.e. $k$ range over all positive integers with an additional constraint that $k$ is smaller than the number of vertices in the graph being considered.

Comment: Duplicate of [determine the language of the independent set problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77804).

Comment: What is $P_{IndependentSet}$? Please define this problem formally then you may find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A language $L$ describes decision problem $p$ means that $\forall x \in L $ the instance $x$ is a Yes/Accept instance of $p$.

For the independent set problem, we have to define language $L$ such that every $x\in L$ is an independent set of graph $G=(V, E)$.

So one possible way to define decision language for independent set problem is
$$\begin{array}{ll}
L & = \{I \mbox{ such that } I\subseteq V \mbox{ and }\forall u,v\in I,\;\; (u,v)\notin E\} \\
& = \{I \;\;|\;\; I\subseteq V \mbox{ and }\forall u,v\in I, \;\; (u,v)\notin E\}
\end{array}
.$$

If you wish to define the language generally you can write it as
$$ \begin{array}{ll}
L & =\{(G=(V,E),I) \mbox{ such that } I\subseteq V \mbox{ and }\forall u,v\in I,\;\; (u,v)\notin E\}\\
 & =\{(G=(V,E),I) \;\;|\;\;  I\subseteq V \mbox{ and }\forall u,v\in I,\;\; (u,v)\notin E\} 
\end{array}
.$$